# send variables to Visual Studio 2008 build event command line

Tags: visual-studio-2008, batch-file, build-events

I would like to send additional parameters to the batch file that I'm running in the "Pre-build event command line" of Visual Studio 2008. I can change directory ("cd") to the current "solution directory" by passing in "$(SolutionDir)\MyProject".

Can I pass in the build version? I've set my AssemblyInfo.cs to auto increment (as described here : http://blog.mbcharbonneau.com/2007/03/13/auto-incrementing-build-numbers-in-visual-studio/)

Thanks @jeffamaphone. If you actually answer, I can accept.

Alternatively, I finally found something similar here as well.
http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSBuildEvents.aspx

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115357/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-build-properties-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this in 2k8, but in 2k3 and 2k5 I used the trick of setting env-vars in the event command ... it can be multiples and IIRC they effectively run as a batch-script under one instanced of cmd.exe.

e.g.:
set BUILD_VERSION=$(BuildVersion)
cd "$(SolutionDir)\MYproject"
rem do more stuff

Comment: I would have thought so as well. Either that or "$(ApplicationRevision)". Both are just outputting "". Weird

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I was not able to get $(BuildVersion) or $(ApplicationRevision) to work. Another member of my team built a small .exe file that retrieved the Version Number from the web project dll file.